# How to change a button image in MDI parent form from child forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried everywhere but not found a solution for my question, so I came here to ask from you guys and hope to get a solution.

I have a MDI and few child forms where on MDI form I have a sidepanel control and it has few buttons control and I what to change button image of these button dynamically from child form.

```
MDImenu frmMDImenu = new MDImenu();
frmMDImenu.btnConnect.Image = Properties.Resources.connect_icon;
```

all buttons images store in Property.Recources

by applying these code I can change the icon/image to button in MDI form from child form but the effect doesn't apply to button. Any suggestion where I am missing something.

Comment: You created a "new" MDImenu form.  You never showed it.  You want a "reference" to the existing form on the screen.

Comment: what exact is your question ? Do you have a button on your main form and you want to change its image from code that is on a mdichild form ?

Answer (score 0):

@Sourav Sarkar,

I have soled it by applying the following codes....

```
frmMDIParent mdiForm = (frmMDIParent)this.MdiParent;
mdiForm.button1.Image = MyProject.Properties.Resources.OK_icon;
```

I didn't applied your code but I should be good too.

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score -1):

There are some steps need to follow to achieve this.

1. In your child form(e.g. Form1)
   create a static variable

```
    public static MDImenu frmMDImenu=null;
```

2. in your MDI form
   when you are opening the child form

```
    Form1 f1=new Form1();
    Form1.frmMDImenu=this;
    f1.MDIparent=this;
    f1.show();
```

3. now where you want to change the image of the button
   Button's Modifier property should be public

```
   frmMDImenu.btnConnect.Image = Properties.Resources.connect_icon;
```

May be this is not the efficient way to solve this. Who cares.
It will solve your problem.